# I would like to know how to insert 2 timestamps into the same spreadsheet

Tags: timestamp

I am trying to insert 2 timestamps one is the time when the cloumn next to it changes information and the other is the date when the column next to it changes

I have tried to search the web but cannot find an answer

```
function onEdit(event){
  var timezone = "GMT+1";
  var timestamp_format = "HH:mm"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Review Date";
  var timeStampColName = "Time";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


      var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
      var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
      var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
      var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
      var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
      if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
        var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
        var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
        cell.setValue(date);
      }
    }
```

This works for changing the time but this does not work when trying to change the date.

```
    function onEdit() {
     var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
       var r = s.getActiveCell();
       if( r.getColumn() == 10) { //checks the column(J)
         var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2); //offset to same row, and column L; J+1
         if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) { //is empty?
           var time = new Date();
           time = Utilities.formatDate(time,"DD-mm-yy");
           nextCell.setValue(time);
         };
       };
       if( r.getColumn() == 8) { //checks the column(H)
         var nextCell = r.offset(0,1); //offset to same row, and column I; H+1
         if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) { //is empty?
           var time = new Date();
         time = Utilities.formatDate(time,"HH-mm");
         nextCell.setValue(time);
         };
       };
     };
    };
```